# Error error C3861: 'cvPyrSegmentation': identifier not found

Tags: c++, undefined-function

Could you please help me???Getting an error when executing coding below. I'm a newbie using OpenCV. My teacher is Mr. Google and you guys who expert in this field.

IntelliSense: identifier "cvPyrSegmentation" is undefined

Error error C3861: 'cvPyrSegmentation': identifier not found

```
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>


 static void help(void)
{
  printf("\nThis program present the function of pyramid segmentation which is   
        cvcvPyrSegmentation()\n""we can controlled the value of threshold by creating 
        the taskbar\n""Usage :\n");            
}

IplImage*  image[2] = { 0, 0 }, *image0 = 0, *image1 = 0;
CvSize size;

int  w0, h0,i;
int  threshold1, threshold2;
int  l,level = 4;
int sthreshold1, sthreshold2;
int  l_comp;
int block_size = 1000;
float  parameter;
double threshold;
double rezult, min_rezult;
int filter = CV_GAUSSIAN_5x5;
CvConnectedComp *cur_comp, min_comp;
CvSeq *comp;
CvMemStorage *storage;

CvPoint pt1, pt2;



static void START_SEGMENT(int a)
{
  (void) a;
  cvPyrSegmentation (image0, image1, storage, &comp, level, threshold1+1,  
  threshold2+1);

  cvShowImage("Segmentation", image1);
}

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
  char* filename;

  help();

  filename = argc == 2 ? argv[1] : (char*)"C:/Users/acer/Documents/Visual Studio   
  2012/Projects/me2.jpg";

  if( (image[0] = cvLoadImage( filename, 1)) == 0 )
{
  help();
  printf("Cannot load fileimage - %s\n", filename);
  return -1;
}


  cvNamedWindow("Source", 0);
  cvShowImage("Source", image[0]);

  cvNamedWindow("Segmentation", 0);

  storage = cvCreateMemStorage ( block_size );

  image[0]->width &= -(1<<level);
  image[0]->height &= -(1<<level);

  image0 = cvCloneImage( image[0] );
  image1 = cvCloneImage( image[0] );
  // segmentation of the color image
  l = 1;
  threshold1 =255;
  threshold2 =30;

  START_SEGMENT(1);

  sthreshold1 = cvCreateTrackbar("Threshold1", "Segmentation", &threshold1, 255,   
  START_SEGMENT);
  sthreshold2 = cvCreateTrackbar("Threshold2", "Segmentation",  &threshold2, 255, 
  START_SEGMENT);

  cvShowImage("Segmentation", image1);
  cvWaitKey(0);

  cvDestroyWindow("Segmentation");
  cvDestroyWindow("Source");

  cvReleaseMemStorage(&storage );

  cvReleaseImage(&image[0]);
  cvReleaseImage(&image0);
  cvReleaseImage(&image1);

  return 0;
}

 #ifdef _EiC
 main(1,"pyramid_segmentation.c");
 #endif
```

Comment: Do you get this error when you compile the code or when you run it?

Comment: Are you passing the correct linking flags to the compiler?

Comment: Get this error when I tried to "Build the solution"...For sure i cant run it if there is an error..Do you know whats wrong with my coding??

Comment: You miss the necessary header file. Try to add #include <cv.h>

Comment: Are sure ??Because when I added #include <cv.h> , there is another error..No such file or directory.. ?_?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't include the right header, by the looks of things.

```
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc_c.hpp>
```

Comment: Unless that function is defined as a macro, it shouldn't be raising a fatal exception.

Comment: @randomusername: Huh? Nobody's said anything about "a fatal exception". The OP has a compiler error, because the function he's trying to use has not been declared in that scope.

Comment: @ApipNate: I already helped you no need to beg. I've set you on the correct path -- now you have to perform the next step on your own, using documentation and even just reading through the header files yourself, to find out what goes where.

Comment: Thank you...please look at this question( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20548462/error-lnk1120-solved-after-removing-some-header-but-then-there-is-another-error ). I cant answer my own question, so I start with a new question.

Comment: @ApipNate: Posting it as a new question was The Right Thing To Do™.

Answer (score 0):

Your compiler can't understand what the command `cvPyrSegmentation` means.  Your solutions are:

1. That particular function doesn't actually exist and you are reading the wrong documentation (I can't find that function in the official API).
2. You might be missing a header file.  Go back to what ever example you are following and redo it exactly as they demonstrate.  If you're not following an example, find one; this is almost always the best way to solve a problem.
3. You might be missing a number of flags that you have to pass to the compiler.  If you're familiar with using libraries you'll know what I mean.  If you're not familiar with using libraries in C, look up how to use a very simply one first.  I suggest the GMP.

If you can't find an example, leave a comment, and I'll edit one in once I find one.

Comment: It's right there in [the reference](http://www.seas.upenn.edu/~bensapp/opencvdocs/ref/opencvref_cv.htm).

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Then I stand corrected.  Unless the OP is using a version of OpenCV that doesn't match that documentation.

Answer (score 0):

add `#include<cvaux.h>` where the function cvPyrSegmentation lies.

PS: all files to be included for assurance...

```
#include<cv.h>
#include <cvaux.h>
#include <opencv\cxcore.hpp>
#include <opencv.hpp>
#include <nonfree.hpp>
#include <core/core.hpp>
#include <imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <imgproc/imgproc_c.h>
#include <highgui.h>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to :
1) first include legacy.hpp (usually on opencv2/legacy/legacy.hpp)

2) make sure that legacy.hpp is in the "additional dependencies" of the linker input (I am assuming you are using visual C++)